# Using Wi-Fi hardware for ZigBee

Tags: wifi, zigbee

Is it possible to use Wi-Fi adapters for communicating with ZigBee devices? Wi-Fi and ZigBee both use the 2.4 GHz range, so the radio hardware should be identical, right?

Since I can not find any information on this in the web, I suppose there must be some problem, or this is a real stupid question. Are the phy and MAC layers hardwired in Wi-Fi adapters? The rest is software anyway, right?

There is this answer: *[Can I implement ZigBee with generic hardware?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/can-i-implement-zigbee-with-generic-hardware)*

It says:

> You could, but you'd need a radio transceiver with compatible frequency range, modulation, and data rate.

Is IEEE 802.15.4-2003 so different to 802.11-1997, for example, that hardware is not exchangeable? The frequency is the same, so is the modulation, DSSS.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site!  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8997623/6495973) perhaps a related question over on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Zigbee and Wi-Fi operate on different radio frequencies.  While some devices might have both radios, a typical Wi-Fi chip wouldn't understand the Zigbee communication format.